# mount() and jffs2_gcd_mtd0 garbage collector

Tags: c++, linux, mount, sigchld, jffs2

I'm working on a platform running MontaVista Linux 3.1.

I have a C++ application, which for esoteric reasons which I won't go into, has to remount the JFFS2 flash file system quite regularly between read-only and read-write.

When you perform a `int mount(...)` call, specified in `sys/mount.h`, to set the file system read-write, the `jffs2_gcd_mtd0` garbage collector process gets kicked off as you would expect. However, when you repeat the `mount` call to go back to read-only, `jffs2_gcd_mtd0` gets killed, and becomes a defunct process.

After a few minutes, we end up with a shed load of defunct `jffs2_gcd_mtd0` processes, which no matter what we do, we can't get rid of.

I can replicate the problem with the following test app:

```
int main()
{
  while(true)
  {
    mount("/dev/mtdblock/0", "flash", "", MS_REMOUNT|MS_POSIXACL|MS_ACTIVE|MS_NOUSER|0XEC0000, "");
    sleep(1);
    mount("/dev/mtdblock/0", "flash", "", MS_RDONLY|MS_REMOUNT|MS_POSIXACL|MS_ACTIVE|MS_NOUSER|0XEC0000, "");
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

I have tried various method to reap the defunct processes: setting `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)` (doesn't work); calling `wait(int)` after the set to read-only (fails, with errno going to 10 - "No child processes"); calling `kill(0, SIGCHLD)` (doesn't work).

Am I correct in assuming this is a bug in the `mount` implementation we have? Given that this is a bug, how could I remove the defunct processes, and stop the process ID table from filling up?

---

Some supplementary info: this problem doesn't seem to occur when I run the test app with `strace`. Now I'm getting really stumped!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the jffs2 code.  I wonder if doing a umount() before the mount() call would help avoid it?

Comment: `strace` slows things down so it could be a race condition in jffs2 filesystem driver code.  Try compiling the latest jffs2 driver from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/fs/jffs2.  Do you see any errors in the logs of `dmesg` output?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Unfortunately calling `umount()` first doesn't make a scrap of difference I'm afraid, and `dmesg` doesn't show any useful output either. I think I've found a workaround, which I'll outline below, so think I can live with this bug. But if I continue to have problems, then I'll try and recompile the jffs2 driver.

Comment: Any reason you don't post this issue on the kernel of jffs2 mailing list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, I have found that calling the `mount()` command from within a `pthread` allows the defunct `jffs2_gcd_mtd0` processes to be reaped.

I believe this is working via the following mechanism: when the thread joins, the spawned `jffs2_gcd_mtd0` process is left without a parent. It therefore gets inherited by `init`, which then gets reaped when it is finished.

If anyone would like to correct/expand on my explanation above, please do!